# How do I show the subsection name and the subsubsection number and name in a fancyhdr header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, titleps

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % displays the section (1. SECTION NAME)
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark} % displays the subsection (1.1 SUBSECTION NAME)
\fancyfoot[R]{\thesubsubsection \subsubsectionname}  % doesn't work
% would like the above line to produce (1.1.1 Subsubsection name), for example.

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Updated example that exhibits the problems I'm having:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[auth-sc,affil-it]{authblk}

\title{A Title}

\author[1]{An Author\thanks{\texttt{email@email}}}
\affil{Department of LateX}

\date{Dated: \today}

\newpagestyle{mypage}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead{ \thesection\quad \sectiontitle }{ \thesubsection\quad \subsectiontitle }{ \thesubsubsection\quad \subsubsectiontitle }
  \setfoot{Generated: \today \hspace{1ex} \currenttime}{\thepage}{Some other footer text}
  \footrule
}
%\settitlemarks{section, subsection, subsubsection} % cannot do this!!
\settitlemarks{section,subsection,subsubsection} % must NOT put spaces in this!
\pagestyle{mypage}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{Section one}
\kant[1-4]
\subsection{Subsection one}
\kant[5-10]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\kant[11-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a complete, small document which demonstrates the issue. As it stands, the obvious answer is, 'Of course it doesn't work. You haven't even `\begin{document}` yet, let alone included any subsubsections!' which is likely rather unhelpful.

Comment: There is no really straightforward way to do what I think you are trying to do with `fancyhdr`. However, I may not have understood.

Comment: @cfr updated example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can't do this easily with `fancyhdr`, you can do it fairly straightforwardly with `titleps`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps,kantlipsum}
\newpagestyle{mypage}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead{\MakeUppercase{\thesection\quad \sectiontitle}}{}{\thesubsection\quad \subsectiontitle}
  \setfoot{}{}{\thesubsubsection\quad \subsubsectiontitle}
}
\settitlemarks{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\pagestyle{mypage}

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\kant[1-4]
\subsection{Subsection one}
\kant[5-10]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\kant[11-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier headers and footers]

Comment: Trying to stick with fancyhdr, though this does look like a useful alternative.

Comment: @BrianD I default to `fancyhdr` myself. I used something else here because it is much more straightforward and probably much more reliable than anything I could cook up myself. See [Werner's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236705/how-do-i-show-the-subsection-name-and-the-subsubsection-number-and-name-in-a-fan/236716?noredirect=1#comment561252_236715) - manipulating LaTeX's marks is one of the Dark Arts.

Comment: @BrianD The subsubsection information just is not saved in the same way as the section and subsection information. You can get the section number - although it might not always be the one you'd expect - but getting the title requires something further. `titleps` has special facilities for creating, saving and utilising marks and is far and away superior to `fancyhdr` for a job with your desiderata.

Comment: a fair point.  I tried both answers and they work fine with a trivial example, but start to break down in my full document.  I end up with the subsub/sub/section numbers but no titles with your solution... not sure why.  I also get subsubsections listed that don't exist (i.e., 1.1.0 in the header when that subsubsection does not exist in my document)

Comment: found the error in my code that was causing the subsection and subsubsection titles not to generate... ugh.

Comment: @BrianD So did you solve the problems?

Comment: I found that `\settitlemarks{section,subsection,subsubsection}` without space after comma works, but `\settitlemarks{section, subsection, subsubsection}` does not work. It was a surprise for me.

Comment: @Roah That is different code. `subsection` is not the same as ` subsection`. Sometimes, spaces are trimmed from input, but not generally.

Comment: Your answer correct my typesetting error, thanks.